# How to format this JSON data to date(mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: javascript, json, date, datetime, datetime-format

Sample JSON:

```
[{"DispatchDt":"2014-05-28T01:34:00","RcvdDt":"1988-12-26T00:00:00"}]
```

I have this set of dates and I want to convert it to the date format (mm/dd/yyyy). How do you do this is JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Comment: Could you be more specific? 1) do you want the first or the second date out? So are you looking for 05/28/3014 or 12/26/1988. 2) Do you want the result in an object? In a variable? Please give expected output and we can help.

Comment: @Monthy: the question is already specific. OP has a date that is stored in a string in a given format and they need to reformat it into `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @Monthy i think what she exactly wanna try to do is to change the format value of those datetime to date only.

Comment: @Kaii that's easy but what makes you say that? Also the above is not fully JSON, but that's another point.

Comment: @Monthy: "is not fully JSON" --- what do you mean by that? It's a valid JSON

Comment: @Monthy To be more specific 1) both 2) variable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may format the json string into `new Date()` then use js methods to get month,day,year or what exactly you need.

```
   //format string to datetime
   var DispatchDt = new Date(this.DispatchDt);


   // then use this methods to fetch date,month, year needed
   //getDate() // Returns the date
   //getMonth() // Returns the month
   //getFullYear() // Returns the year
    var DispatchDt_date = DispatchDt.getDate();
    var DispatchDt_month = DispatchDt.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var DispatchDt_year = DispatchDt.getFullYear();
```

[Sample on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiifalcutela/unu4p/4/)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately parsing and formatting dates is a weak side of javascript.

So usually for that we use the 3rd party libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

An example of how you would do that with `moment.js`:

```
var date = '2014-05-28T01:34:00';

var parsedDate = moment(date);

var formattedDate = parsedDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8gzFW/

Comment: how bout without using any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: @LYKS: any reason to not use convenient tools? You may parse and format *manually* if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
var a = "[{"DispatchDt":"2014-05-28T01:34:00","RcvdDt":"1988-12-26T00:00:00"}]";
var b = JSON.parse(c);
for (i in b[0]) {
  b[0][i] = b[0][i].slice(0, 9) 
}
console.log(b); // b now looks like this [ { DispatchDt: "2014-05-28", RcvDt: "1988-12-26" } ]
```

Please note the dates are stringified.

Comment: 1. There are issues with quotes in the first line 2. `2014-05-28` is not in an expected format